# Pyspark dataframe: creating column based on other column values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, format-string

I have a pyspark dataframe:

[image]

Now, I want to add a new column called "countryAndState", where, for example for the first row, the value would be "USA_CA". I have tried several approaches, the last one was the following:

```
df_2 = df.withColumn("countryAndState", '{}_{}'.format(df.country, df.state))
```

I have tried with `"country"` and `"state"` instead, or with simply `country` and `state`,and also using `col()` but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Python format strings in Spark. Use `concat` instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_2 = df.withColumn("countryAndState", F.concat(F.col('country'), F.lit('_'), F.col('state')))
```

or `concat_ws`, if you need to chain many columns together with a given separator:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_2 = df.withColumn("countryAndState", F.concat_ws('_', F.col('country'), F.col('state')))
```